# divide a 4-digit integer into 2-digit integers and calculate by c

Tags: c

//Enter a 4-digit integer n from the keyboard, and write a program to divide it into two 2-digit integers a and B. Calculate and output the results of the addition, subtraction, multiplication, division and redundancy operations of the split two numbers. For example, n=-4321, if the two integers after splitting are a and b, then a=-43 and b=-21. The result of division operation requires that it be precise to 2 decimal places, and the data type is float. Redundancy and division operations need to take into account the division of 0, that is, if the split B = 0, then output the prompt information "The second operator is zero!"

//Failure to pass the test，how should i fix

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    int x, a, b;
    printf("Please input n:\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    a = x / 100;
    b = x % 100;
    printf("%d,%d\n", a, b);
    printf("sum=%d,sub=%d,multi=%d\n", a + b, a - b, a*b);
    if (b == 0)
        printf("The second operater is zero!");
    else
        printf("dev=%.2f,mod=%d\n", (float)a / b, a%b);
}
```

Comment: Works for me, what input gives you the wrong output?

Comment: Can you clarify your question with a test case that does not work as expected? The one you gave produces the expected result.

Comment: I submit this code online, and the web page simply feedback a failed result. I don't know the exact reason too

Comment: Please note that online judges usually need the output formatted in a very specific way. Also, but it may be too nitpicking, if by "redundancy" you mean [remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder), note that in number theory the *least positive remainder* is always positive, unlike the result of `%`.

Comment: Curious, why cast to `(float)` in `(float)a / b` vs. `(double)a / b`?  Note: In the first case, the `float` quotient is promoted to `double` when passed as a `...` argument.  The 2nd case incurs no type change.

Comment: "Redundancy" and "I don't know the exact reason too" are unclear/insuffcient here.  Provide sample input **and** expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to check that `x` is a 4-digits number. So if the input is `12345` or `123` you don't satisfy the requirement.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int x, a, b;
    int passed = 0;

    // Enter a 4 digits number: ABCD
    do {
        printf("Enter X = ");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        passed = (x >= 1000 && x <= 9999) || (x >= -9999 && x <= -1000);
    } while (!passed);

    a = x / 100;
    b = x % 100;

    printf("Numbers: %d %d \n", a, b);

    printf("Sum = %d \n", a + b);
    printf("Sub = %d \n", a - b);
    printf("Mul = %d \n", a * b);
    if (0 == b) {
        printf("Div by Zero \n");    
    } else {
        printf("Div = %f \n", (double)a / b);
        printf("Mod = %d \n", a % b);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: to check `scanf("%d", &x)` returns 1 can be useful ;-)

Comment: @bruno yes I agree, to prevent user from inputs like `1234a`, `xyzt`,...

Comment: @bruno can you give me more detail with code about "how to check scanf("%d", &x) returns 1"?